# Python3 polymorphism: Does anyone else get a NameError in Chapter14 of John Guttag's Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python 2ed?

Tags: python-3.x, polymorphism

I'm new to Python but stuck on this and as it seems a nice way to implement polymorphism want to understand why the model code (ie the one the Professor uses in the text) does not work on my system. I doubt it's a bug in the code - more likely a system inconsistency somewhere on my part. Thanks if anyone looks at this.

The example is meant to show how to use classes and polymorphism in the context of 2D random walks. The below will only make sense if you read the code in the book pages 219 to 222 and understand what it is trying to do. I coded the model source code; kept getting same error so downloaded the website's source code and get the same error. The error occurs where Guttag defines functions that take arguments (that seem to be implicitly of type 'class') called dClass. The model code then calls these functions passing the argument UsualDrunk (and then later other subclasses) which is a defined subclass of the class Drunk. I see how it should work: but running ipython 7.2.0 or python 3.5.2 I get NameError: name UsualDrunk is not defined. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or my python version is incomptatible with the source code. Ubuntu Linux input/output is:

```
$ ls
chapter14.py
$ ipython
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import chapter14                                                        

In [2]: chapter14.drunkTest((10,100,1000),1000,UsualDrunk)                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-90a872f15ce9> in <module>
----> 1 chapter14.drunkTest((10,100,1000),1000,UsualDrunk)

NameError: name 'UsualDrunk' is not defined
```

The book's Webpage that has the souce code is https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-computation-and-programming-using-python-revised-and-expanded-edition

Comment: Please include the relevant code that you are using directly in your post, instead of linking to an external site.

Comment: The name `UsualDrunk` is unknown. Perhaps it just needs to be replaced with `chapter14.UsualDrunk`.

Comment: Thanks - that works.